# Sitelinks disappearing the day after being generated

Tags: seo, google, google-search

I am currently performing SEO for a company website. It is made in Nuxt v2 with Nuxt i18n module for multilingual support.

I have an issue with sitelinks disappearing. Two weeks ago, sitelinks for the website were generated for the first time. The description for pages was the same, but I figured that if I place a new description or omit it altogether it would be fixed. However, the next day after I reported sitelink generation, they simply disappeared from the search.

Ever since then, I have done the following:

- Added noindex tags for pages which I do not want to be indexed, such
  as privacy policy and mail form responses.
- Added unique descriptions for all important pages.
- Initiated indexing through Google Search Console.

If anyone had this kind of problem, what did you do to make sitelinks reappear again? What are good practices when it comes to this issue?

Please let me know in the comments. Thank you!